This "CRIT" billboard GUI isn't working, how to fix it?
so the output says that Workspace.Knife.Script:58: attempt to index nil with 'Character'
here is the code shown
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = player.Character
local hum = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                    
local gui = Instance.new("BillboardGui")

gui.Parent = hum.Parent.Head
gui.Adornee = hum.Parent.Head
gui.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 50)
gui.StudsOffset = Vector3.new(0, 2, 0)
                    
local text = Instance.new("TextLabel")
                    
text.Parent = gui
text.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
text.BackgroundTransparency = 1
text.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(223, 204, 0)
text.TextScaled = true
text.Text = "1.75x"

wait(1)
                    
gui:Destroy()
                    
hit.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(8*1.75)
hitboxActivated = false


how do i this it?

From the error message, it says Workspace.Knife.Script which indicates you are using a Script and not a LocalScript (unless you changed the name of LocalScript to Script).
In your code, you use local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer but you can't get LocalPlayer if you are not in a LocalScript because Script runs on the server and has no LocalPlayer.
Consider changing the class of your script from Script to LocalScript so you can use LocalPlayer.
